# Submitting an empty text field as an empty string, not null, in a multipart form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, multipartform-data, enctype

This is happening in my Rails app, but I'm not sure whether this is an issue with Rails or if I'm misunderstanding how multipart forms are supposed to work.

Here's (something like) my form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

`User#name` has a presence validation. If I visit `users/1/edit`, empty out the value of the 'name' text field, and click submit, nothing gets updated because the presence validation fails. So far, so good.

But now I've added an `avatar` attribute to my User (using the Paperclip gem for file storage), so I update the form accordingly:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

*Now*, if I go to edit the user and submit a blank value for `name`, the validation doesn't fail. `User#name` keeps it previous value, but the update still appears to be successful (i.e. I don't get an error message about failed validations and the `updated_at` timestamp in the database gets updated.)

On closer inspection, it seems that when I include a `file_field` in the form, it changes the form's behaviour when submitting blank text fields (probably due to the fact that `form_for` now outputs a form with `enctype=-"multipart/form-data"`).

When the `file_field` *isn't* present, submitting a blank `name` sends these params to the server:

`{ "id" => 1, "user" => { "name: "" }`

Which results in something like `User.find(1).update_attributes(name: "")` in the controller, which of course fails to update because Rails sees that we're trying to update 'name' to a blank string and the validation fails.

When it *is* present, this gets submitted:

`{ "id" => 1, "user" => { }` (plus extra info about the avatar file)

The "name" key isn't present at all, so the controller runs `User.find(1).update_attributes()` which of course passes as there's nothing being updated that might fail a validation.

Is this a bug, or a feature? Why would changing the enctype to multipart  (assuming that's the source of the problem) change the way blank text fields behave? (I've tested this in both Chrome and FF, fwiw.) If this is really the intended behaviour, how can I ensure that blank text fields get submitted properly without having to add a bunch of tedious boilerplate around every text field?

(If it matters, I'm using: Ruby 2.3.0, Rails 5.0.0.beta3, Paperclip 5.0.0.beta1, and I've tested in Chrome 49 and Firefox 45)

Comment: Strange, I am unable to reproduce the behavior you describe. In my case (Rails 4.2 though), the blank name is _always_ sent as an empty string: `"name" => ""`, regardless of the form encoding type. Maybe you could try the same code on Rails 4 to possibly find a Rails 5 change in behavior (or even bug)?

Comment: Also please see [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36501726/revisions) that I think was needed so that the question actually makes sense and revert it if I misunderstood you.

Comment: yes, your edit is correct. Thanks for catching my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, updating Rails to the latest version fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, I was using one of the beta versions of Rails 5.0.0. Upgrading to the RC seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like that

```
updated_user = User.new(your_params) # The new attributes is set to a new object record    
target_user = User.find(params[:id]) # the user you want to update
target_user = updated_user

    if target_user.save?
    ..
    else
    ..
```

by this all the validations will be triggered and the active record will have all the new attributes, if the name is blank it'll catch it

Comment: Doesn't work. Your first three lines functionally are equivalent to `target_user = User.new(your_params)` which will create a new user, not update an existing one - and the problem isn't that `User` can't catch blank names, the problem is that `params[:user][:name]` is blank in the first place (the key `:name` isn't present) when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Yea now I get it, sounds weird, did you try other gem like carrierwave and the same behavior happened ?

Answer (score 0):

The following strong param method won't bring back the dropped :name parameter, but it should prevent the form from imitating a successful submit:

```
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar)
  end
```

This can be inserted as a private method under your Users Controller. Then simply call user_params in your Update method.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I already have a `_params` method for Strong Parameters.